# How to assign all user objects to db_owner role

Tags: postgresql

Database contains user objects owned by postgres.
It is required that all user objects in database will be owner by role db_owner.

I tried to reassign them to db_owner role ussing

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY postgres TO db_owner
```

but got error

```
ERROR:  cannot reassign ownership of objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system
```

How to assign all user objects to db_owner role?

Using

"PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit"

database was restored from 9.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is impossible, because the system objects have to be owned by the *bootstrap superuser* (in your case `postgres`).

You should not mess with the system objects.

If you have non-system objects owned by `postgres`, identify them and change ownership one by one.

If it is just the name that disturbs you, you can rename `postgres` to `db_owner`, but I think that is not what you want.

Comment: I dont want to change system objects owner. I want to change only non-system objects owner in this database from postgres to db_owner

Comment: As I said, you'll have to do it one by one.